# Is there a way to configure Firebase security rules consider data sent to server on a read?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I don't want to require authentication for users to query data from a specific node in my Firebase database ... BUT, I do want them to supply a "key" in their read request that is validated in Firebase using its security rules.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you share the JSON data structure (as text, no images please) that the user would be reading from and the code for a read operation that would fail and one that would succeed?

Comment: In this scenario, a "read" operation should only succeed if the user passed a GUID key as part of the request ... as part of the HTTP header or query string.  I could even make this work if I could simply pass the auth.token back as part of the querystring.

Comment: yes, that is possible. Not sure why you would do it however since Firebase has Authentication and Rules.